# how to export image width original width and height, even if zoom is not 1 on Konva.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, react-konva

I am developing image editor with konva.js

I want to export image with scale 1, even if scale is not 1.

But, In my sample code, I did set scale to 1, I didn't get image of scale 1 from Konva.js

Any ideas?

my example code is same as [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-haibt-mmu5pt?file=/src/App.js:117-1475)

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the scale to 1, export and then restore the original scale. You don't need to clone stage for that.

```js
const stageNode = stageRef.current;

if (stageNode) {
  // Save the current scale value so we can restore it later
  const prevScaleX = stageNode.scaleX();
  const prevScaleY = stageNode.scaleY();

  // Reset the scale to 1
  stageNode.scale({
    x: 1,
    y: 1
  });

  const dataUrl = stageNode.toDataURL();
  console.log("dataUrl:", dataUrl);

  // Restore the previous scale value
  stageNode.scale({
    x: prevScaleX,
    y: prevScaleY
  });
```